# Polymer `iron-localstorage` real time data-binding

Tags: data-binding, polymer, local-storage

## Context

- Polymer `1.8.1`
- iron-localstorage `1.0.6`

Hi! I am trying to set a localstorage data and get its value from another element in real time.

## Problem

I am never notified of the localstorage update, so it changes only on reload

## [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/QgQrhIOco6ROzwmoXUNN?p=preview)

Comment: I get real time updates on your demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<iron-localstorage>` can't know you updated localStorage manually. You have to tell him to reload data. That's why it has `reload()` function. So, if you want to reload data 5 times per sec, you have call `reload()` 5 times per sec

so something like:

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.$$("iron-localstorage").reload();
},200)
```